# virsh console hangs whenever I connect to Virtual Machine

Tags: kvm, virsh

Whenever I try to connect to VM using `virsh console <vm name>` my screen hangs and displays:

```
Connected to domain <vm name>
Escape character is ^]
```

I have found many solutions on the internet but nothing has worked for me and I am even not able to find the `/etc/init` directory as CentOS 7 has a different directory structure.

I need `/etc/init` directory to create a script which I found on the internet as a solution.

I am using only ssh connection and no GUI and I do not have any access to the physical machine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I have tidied up your post as it was difficult to understand exactly what you are asking, however I think you would be better placed to ask this question on our sister site [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) please have a read of ["How to ask a good question"](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start a console (e.g. ttyS0 ). 
For example on my Debian 8 I enable it with systemd:

```
systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
```

[Enable Serial Console on CentOS/RHEL 7](https://kernelmanic.com/2015/10/14/enable-serial-console-on-centosrhel-7/)

On the virtual machine, add ‘console=ttyS0‘ at the end of the kernel lines in the /boot/grub2/grub.cfg file:

```
grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="console=ttyS0"
```

**Note:** Alternatively, you can edit the /etc/default/grub file, add `console=ttyS0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable and execute

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial –speed115200 –unit=0 –word=8 –parity=no –stop=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right after virt-install, then after trying to connect to the guest, too. I tried all the suggested solutions but none of them helped. Then I realized that I forgot to install KVM. A simple 'yum -y install kvm' resolved the issue.